# FragmentManager: popBackStack() and IllegalStateException

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have **Activity**:

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener
{
    ...

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed()
    {
        if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    }
}
```

**SimpleFragmentManager**:

```
private static void moveTo(BaseFragment fragment)
{
    if(fragment != null)
    {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = _activity.getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

        //this  
        //ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_CLOSE);
        //or this   
        //ft.setCustomAnimations(R.animator.enter, R.animator.exit, R.animator.enter, R.animator.exit);
        //or this
        //ft.setCustomAnimations(R.animator.enter, R.animator.exit);

        BaseFragment currentFragment = getCurrentFragment();

        if(fragment != currentFragment)
        {
            ft.replace(_containerId, fragment, fragment.getType());
            if (currentFragment != null)
            {
                ft.addToBackStack(null);
            }
            ft.commit();
        }
    }
}
```

Example my **Fragment**:

```
public class AFragment extends BaseFragment
{
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        if(view == null)
        {
            view = new ALayout(container.getContext());
            view.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        }

        return view;
    }
}
```

**>>PROBLEM<<**

The test is this, I'm on a **fragment A**, then I turn on the **fragment B**, then I immediately change the process of animation pieces, I click the back button at the bottom of the screen.

From the first time this can not happen, but making these steps several times, application crashes with an error:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                               Process: com.my.application, PID: 2103
>                                                               java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a
>   parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
>                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:4309)
>                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:4145)
>                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:4086)
>                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:4059)
>                                                                   at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:985)
>                                                                   at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1148)
>                                                                   at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:793)
>                                                                   at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1535)
>                                                                   at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:482)
>                                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
>                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

This error occurs only if you use the transition animation, here is this:

```
ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_CLOSE);
```

or

```
ft.setCustomAnimations(R.animator.enter, R.animator.exit, R.animator.enter, R.animator.exit);
```

or

```
ft.setCustomAnimations(R.animator.enter, R.animator.exit);
```

If you do not use transition animations, then there is no error!

I have found many of these topics, and also found that there is a bug API:

1) https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=77670

2) https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=89244

My SDK version:

```
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'
```

**The important thing, in the fragment I did not delete *View* this:**

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
        ...
        ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
        if(parent != null) parent.removeView(view);
}
```

Because I want to use a **single View**!

Tell me please as it is possible to correct this error?

**>>P.S. One of the variants of the solution:** *disable the Back button while there is animation fragments.*

Comment: Whats mean by "I want to use a single View" ? currently i'm facing the same problem and at the end have to solve it by checking the parent everytimes the fragment is resumed.

Comment: Did you got any solution to it?

Comment: @PravinsinghWaghela build tools from 25 and higher don't have this bug.

Comment: @0x131313 Thanks, Built tool means gradle build version or app os version?

Comment: @PravinsinghWaghela buildToolsVersion

Comment: @0x131313 Thanks Buddy...

Comment: am facing this issue in "buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'" too while using navigation with androidx

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem with API 28. Sometimes I want manually to pop backstack just after fragment is created. Direct invokation of popBackStack gives me this error. Here is my solution (kotlin):

```
activity.supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().runOnCommit {
    activity.supportFragmentManager.popBackStack()
}.commit()
```

It's quite ugly, but I didn't find any better solution. In your case, you could use

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0)
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().runOnCommit(
            () -> getFragmentManager().popBackStack()
        ).commit();
}
```